# facebook api file upload getting 324 error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using php facebook api **4.0**. I'm using below code to post photo on my timeline.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_sc);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($url_page);
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
$session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false); 

if($session) {
  try {
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'source' => '@' . realpath('1.jpg'),
        'message' => 'message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
    // If you're not using PHP 5.5 or later, change the file reference to:
    // 'source' => '@/path/to/file.name'
    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

But I'm getting `Exception occured, code: 324 with message: (#324) Requires upload file` error. I think one thing is that, **fileupload support** should be set to on. But I don't know from where should I turn it on.

Comment: **Update:** Try adding: `'fileUpload' => true,` to the facebook's new instance: `$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $fbconfig['appid'],
'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'], ...`

Comment: Where should I put `'fileUpload' => true` ?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Go check the example under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0

Comment: Like this: `$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => $fbconfig['appid'], 'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'], ... ,'fileUpload' => true));`

Comment: There are two ways to do this: using 'CURLFile' (docs example) or using '@path/name' (as you're doing). In both ways you need to make sure you're using the correct path for your image. I believe I had the same issue using relative paths and I fixed it using absolute paths. The error you're getting means that there wasn't a file sent through the API request. I hope it helps.